# MVC 4 (RC) Web Api OData not sorting properly

Tags: json, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, odata, asp.net-web-api

Recently updated to the RC of MVC4.  It fixed a lot of problems, especially around date serialization.  However, I'm having another problem.  The OData sorting and options I was using for paging/sorting, etc. are not working now.  I haven't changed anything in the code and I can't find anything in the release notes that mentions the functionality changed.  My code is below, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Note: I am using the [AttributeRouting extension](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting), not sure if this is causing the problem or not.

---

**Web API Class/Method**

```
[RouteArea("v1")]
[RoutePrefix("locations")]
public class LocationsController : ApiController
{
    // Data Repository
    static readonly IRepository<Location> Repo = new LocationRepository();

    #region CRUD

    [GET("")]
    public IQueryable<Location> Get()
    {
        return Repo.All;
    }
}
```

---

**jQuery Client Call**

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/v1/locations?$orderby=Name asc',
        success: function (data) {
            resultFunction(data);
        }
});
```

---

**JSON Response**

```
[
    {
        "LocationId":"aca3e1fe-8192-4bb8-b233-1d6fe6b69ba4",
        "Name":"Triangle North"
    },
    {
        "LocationId":"0c99a267-2093-401a-9466-70788500630b",
        "Name":"Triangle West"
    },
    {
        "LocationId":"168e3755-b61e-41d6-99f3-941d738ab321",
        "Name":"Triangle East"
    },
    {
        "LocationId":"82e7a547-a4eb-4233-bdb4-cd8c5b369af8",
        "Name":"Triangle South",
    }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out in the course for searching on this MSFT made the decision to require an explicit attribute to be specified in order for the OData stuff to flow automatically:

> (...)You have to put a `[Queryable]` attribute on the method ([docs](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/paging-and-querying)).
>
> ```
> [Queryable]
> public IQueryable<Product> GetAllProducts()
> {
>     return repository.GetAll().AsQueryable();
> }
> ```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1809900.aspx/1?Web+API+OData+in+RC

Doh!